# How do I change default camera app android 12, or how I force my app to use third party camera

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin app that uses xam.media (jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) for photos. In android 10 i was using Open Camera,(user was asked about the camera app he wants).
But in Android 12 this is gone.
The problem is that default camera, after 20-30 pictures, freezes with memory not enough problem.
So
How can i force xam.media to use Open Camera.
Or how can i change default Camera to Open Camera

Thanks In Advance

gave ALL QUERIES permission to manifest. Nothing changed.

Comment: You can open a specific app using its package name for the intent.

Comment: Do not know the procedure. Do u have any articles,documentation in mind?

Comment: I would google for intent to start specific app.

Comment: Starting in Android 11, for instance, users won’t be able to select a default camera app in certain scenarios. But you can try set the other app as the default camera app by double pressing the lock button. I found a similar issue about jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin issues in the GitHub page: [How to select the camera app to take pictures in Android 11](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/954), please follow the progress about it.